# React: Detect which button in form of multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have two buttons:

- save
- save and close

They are both part of (inside) the same [formik](https://formik.org/) form on a component:

```
<Formik initialValues={initialValues}  onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  //... fields
   <submitButton label="save" />
   <submitButton label="save & close" />
</formik>
```

This form triggers this function:

```
const handleSubmit = (values, { setSubmitting }: FormikHelpers<any>) => {
    setFormPreferences({ ...values, assetType: assetTypes[values.assetId] })
    addSnackbar("Preferences Saved")
  }
```

Inside that `handleSubmit` I added:

```
history.push(from)
```

However it fires on both button clicks. How can I detect if it was the "Save & Close" button that was clicked and then only fire the `history.push(from)`.

for example:

```
if (saveAndCloseButton) {
 history.push(from)
}
```

I am also thinking it might be wise to see if the `setFormPreferences` has worked

Comment: What's in `submitButton`?  How have you wired it to the submit function?

Comment: submitButton is just a component that returns a `<button type="submit"></button>` - this then triggers the onsbumit in formik.

Comment: Why are you using submit button instead of normal buttons ? Refer https://codesandbox.io/s/github/formik/formik/tree/master/examples/field-arrays?from-embed=&file=/index.js

Answer (score 1):

> How do I add that event into the current structure because I have
> values – JamesG

You can pass event like this below code:

```
const handleSubmit = (event, yourParam1, yourParam2, ...) => {
   if (event.currentTarget.name === "button1") {
      history.push(from)
   }
}


<Formik>
  //... fields
   <button name="button1" label="save" onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event, param1, param2, ...)} />
   <button name="button2" label="save & close" onClick={(event) => handleSubmit(event, param1, param2, ...)} />
</formik>
```

[Here is my demo on Code sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bird-ymtkj?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: This doesnt work. Formik handles the click event so I cannot add onClick to the individual buttons.

Comment: Here is my demo on CodeSandBox
https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-bird-ymtkj?file=/src/App.js

These work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

According to the formik docs first argument of the handleSubmit function is an `ReactFormEvent` event.

https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#handlesubmit-e-reactformeventhtmlformelement--void

You should be able to get the target and conditionally take an action by doing:

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
   if (e.currentTarget.value == ...) {
      history.push(from)
   }
}
```

Comment: How do I add that `event` into the current structure because I have `values`

Comment: Your link is to events you get FROM Formik, not that you pass TO Formik.